# Ajax dropdown call to function can't show me all values

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Hello I'm using ajax to call on-change drop-down list and select all value from database into table row format but it only show me the last record from database into table row.
I have three rows in database related to one select from drop-down list and I want to show all three rows into table row format. My code is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#location').change(function(){

            $.ajax({
      url:'location.php?location=' + $(this).val(),
      type: "get",
      timeout:10000,
     dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){

   document.getElementById("material_name").value=data.material_name;

   document.getElementById("material_quantity").value=data.product_quantity;

      },
      error:function(){

      }   
    });             
        });
and location.php page is as:-
    <?php
require_once("shine_class.php");
                $s = new shine;
                $s->connection();
$location = $_REQUEST['location'];
$query ="SELECT * from material_used where product_name = '$location'  ";
$query1=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
 $result1=$row['material_name'];
 $result2=$row['product_quantity'];
}
 echo json_encode(array("material_name"=>$result1,"product_quantity"=>$result2));
?>
```

Comment: in my location.php page json_encode(array("material_name"=>$result1,"product_quantity"=>$result2));                                                          array material_name has three values and i want all these three values into table row in other page but it shows me only last record there...

Comment: i think you should loop through data and append the rows to the table

Comment: try `result1[]` and `result2[]`

Comment: Hi roeb can you explain more how to do this as I'm new to java script Ajax.

Comment: Any help guys how to loop through java script array to load all values into table row format